# Upload document in postman

Tags: postman

Iam facing some challanges by uploading a document in postman. The steps how to upload a document by the body and choosing form-data then you add file and change it to file instead of tekst. This goes fine and when I excute the call it goes through. But when I close the postman call and try to open it again and excuted it gives me 400 error code. When I look into the body and espacially by the form-data it shows that no file is choosing. So postman is not saving the path where the document is located. In this case I have to added everytime when I want to run the request.

The quastion is how do I fix this problem. Postman is not saving the location of the document.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an open postman issue: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4320